# Access denied while accessing Google Drive API from windows shared hosting

Tags: c#, .net, api, oauth

Below code working fine in local environment but facing the issue while running published code on shared hosting environment.

Exception:

One or more errors occurred.

> System.Net.HttpListenerException (0x80004005): Access is denied    at
>   System.Net.HttpListener.AddAllPrefixes()    at
>   System.Net.HttpListener.Start()    at
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.StartListener()    at
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.d__8.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.d__8.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__1.MoveNext()

**My code is :**

```
UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
                new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/GoogleDrive\\client_secret.json"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/GoogleDrive\\credentials\\sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json");

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            }

            var driveService = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

            string folderId = string.Empty;

            folderId = "FolderID here";

            string fileExt = Path.GetExtension(fileuploaded.FileName);

            var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
            {
                Name = FileName + fileExt,
                Parents = new List<string>
                {
                    folderId
                }
            };

            FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
            using (var stream = fileuploaded.InputStream)
            {
                request = driveService.Files.Create(
                    fileMetadata, stream, fileuploaded.ContentType);
                request.Fields = "id";
                request.Upload();
            }

            var file = request.ResponseBody;
```

I have published my code to shared windows hosting. Facing the mentioned error - Access denied. Please help me here to solve this problem.

Comment: Do you launch your app with Administrator rights?

Comment: Can you please help me how to launch?

Comment: If you have an `exe` file, just right click on it and select `Run as Administrator`

Comment: No, Its website developed in MVC which contains dlls only. Published on shared windows hosting.

Comment: If it's web application hosted in IIS, try to change your application pool's identity

Comment: Its' set as ApplicationPoolIdentity and as its a shared hosting so I don't have access to edit pool settings.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? I am having similar problems trying to run from a website